# PyTorch dot product does not work for some cases

Tags: python, pytorch

I am struggling with an issue I cannot solve in PyTorch code.  My task is simple: just get the inner product of two tensors.  However, the output becomes zero in certain cases instead of returning the correct value.

For example, the code below demonstrates the issue.

```
a = torch.tensor([3,1])
b = torch.tensor([3.,1.])
a.dot(a)  # this returns 10, which is correct
b.dot(b)  # this returns 0., which is not correct
```

I am using PyTorch version 1.2 and this has never happened to me before...  Is there something simple that I am missing around the way I define the tensors?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: your code works fine in torch 1.1.0

Comment: Thanks!  I figured out that upgrading Python 3.6.3 to Python 3.6.6 did the job.  I don't know why it happened but now it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the same code using torch version `'1.0.1.post2'` and saw the results `tensor(10)`and `tensor(10.)` respectively for `a.dot(a)` and `b.dot(b)`. Please confirm if you are missing something else in the code.

Comment: Thanks!  From your comment I figured the code was fine, so I tried upgraded Python 3.6.3 to Python 3.6.6, which solved the issue.